# Is there a reality in the DC comics multiverse where the Joker never existed alongside Batman?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, the-joker

Recently, Walter Hamada (*President of DC at WB*) [confirmed](https://www.cbr.com/pattinson-batman-confirmed-separate-earth-from-dceu/) that the Robert Pattinson Batman (*a.k.a* **Battinson**) is from a different Earth with its own existing Justice League. He also mentioned that Batman's arch-nemesis, the Joker does not exist in the Battinson universe.

> "There is that one Earth, that greater Earth with this existing Justice League and another that's sort of happening with that Year Two Batman," Hamada continued, before explaining characters that stood out, such as ***the Joker, who does not exist on either Earth***, "But that's OK. Matt Reeves can continue to build out his Gotham."

This got me thinking. Is there a reality (universe/parallel Earth *etc.*) in the DC comics multiverse where the Joker never existed?

Looking for answers from across the DC comics omniverse (pre/post crisis, New-52, Rebirth; also from the short issues like: Dark Knights Metal, DCeased *etc.*)

Comment: There is now, at least. Are you asking if this was a thing in the comics before?

Comment: @Cubic yes. i'm looking for answers from the comics.

Comment: Because right from Adam West's Batman to WB's Gotham, the Bat always has been represented alongside the Joker

Comment: Is he saying that the Joker doesn't exist in the main DCEU continuity? Even though we've *seen him* in the main DCEU continuity?

Comment: @F1Krazy from what I understood, he says that the Joker exists in the main continuity; however in this parallel universe, there was never a Joker.

Comment: There are multiverse worlds where *humans* never existed such as Earth-C and Earth-C-Plus, Earth-265 (where everyone is a whale), Earth-I (One) (where everyone's an insect), Earth-M (where everyone's a squid), Earth-R (where everyone's a dinosaur) or Earth Omega Prime where the universe never coalesced into stars and planets.

Comment: @valorum, maybe that would be a good edit to the question. "Is there a reality where an earth has batman, but does not have joker?"

Comment: @Valorum: no multiverse world where everyone is an ape? That's just plain [weird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Apes).

Comment: @AncientSwordRage and Paul, thanks for rephrasing the question.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite There was a time when Grodd turned the whole world into apes in *JL: TAS*

Comment: @PaulD.Waite We live in a world where everyone is an ape.

Comment: @Valorum _[YOU MANIAC etc.](https://squidnova.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Planet-of-the-Apes-End-Scene.jpg)_